# annoying clocksource alert/warning in bash prompt periodically

Tags: kernel, lfs, clock, bugs

So I just build LFS system and it's working fine, but the annoying part is there's alert that every periode show like every 3 second.
It said

```
root@LFS:# clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: acpi_pm wd-wd readback delay of 643744ns
clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 182144ns, clock-skew test skipped!
clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: acpi_pm wd-wd readback delay of 643744ns
clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 182144ns, clock-skew test skipped!
clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: acpi_pm wd-wd readback delay of 643744ns
clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 182144ns, clock-skew test skipped!
...
```

This is annoying my bash prompt, I even can't see my output from bash prompt

Comment: Which version of LFS init system are you running : SysVinit or Systemd ?

Comment: @MC68020 SysVinit i think, because i have no seen any Systemd word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are logs from the kernel which default to being displayed on the console (/dev/console) which most probably matches the tty terminal you used for login in.

This is of course usually suboptimal and most systems resort to some specific daemon in order to sort and archive logs :
I personally use [metalog](https://github.com/hvisage/metalog), [syslog-ng](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng) is well known, apparently LFS gets a dedicated packet [sysklogd](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/9.0/chapter06/sysklogd.html)

I suggest you first ensure it is not running already (ps -ef | grep klogd), in which case you would have to correct its configuratrion file, and if not then install it, configure it (edit /etc/syslog.conf) and ensure it is launched at init time the sysVinit way.