# Why dmesg output displayed on /dev/tty1

Tags: tty, stdout, dmesg, pty, pts

This is still related to my [yesterday thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703218/annoying-clocksource-alert-warning-in-bash-prompt-periodically), so there's alert or maybe it's just log that displayed on my terminal on `/dev/tty1`. Ofcourse it's annoying because it's displayed in my bash prompt, so whenever I want input something, my input has been overwrite with that output. It came printed out periodically maybe about `3 second`. So you can see how it's annoying

My terminal is moreless looks like this:

```
root@LFS:# echo "Hey get out of there"clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: acpi_pm wd-wd readback delay of 643744ns
clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 182144ns, clock-skew test skipped!
clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: acpi_pm wd-wd readback delay of 643744ns
clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 182144ns, clock-skew test skipped!
clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: acpi_pm wd-wd readback delay of 643744ns
clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 182144ns, clock-skew test skipped!
...
```

I suspect this is not because of `clocksource`, but `dmesg` output. Because when I command `dmesg`. It display same. But whenever I use `/dev/pts` There's no annoying output or alert that came periodically, I tested it when I login SSH in my LFS sistem.

So how to prevent dmesg log displayed to `/dev/tty1`

Update:
Inside `/proc/cmdline`

```
root@LFS:~# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.16.9-lfs-11.1 root=/dev/sda1 ro
```

Comment: What is the contents of `/proc/cmdline`?

Comment: @icarus I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable console output by reducing the console loglevel. For example, to disable all output by reducing the console loglevel to 0:

```
# sysctl kernel.printk='0 4 0 5'
```

`kernel.printk` takes four arguments:

1. The console loglevel, which controls which messages will be displayed on the console (this is what you mostly care about);
2. The default message loglevel for any messages which don't already have a loglevel set;
3. The minimum console loglevel allowed, which clamps the console loglevel to a minimum;
4. The default console loglevel (currently unused in code).

You can persist this in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

You can also use dmesg to do this using `dmesg`:

```
# dmesg -n1
```

From `man dmesg`:

> **-n, --console-level *level***: Set the level at which messages are logged to the console. The level is a level number or abbreviation of the level name. For example, -n 1 or -n alert prevents all messages except emergency (panic) messages from appearing on the console. All levels of messages are still written to /proc/kmsg, so syslogd(8) can still control exactly where kernel messages appear. When the -n option is used, dmesg will not print or clear the kernel ring buffer. For all supported levels see --help output.

You can also tweak this on the kernel command line by passing `loglevel=N`, see `Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt`. The option `quiet` is also available -- which level it actually sets depends on the value of `CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_QUIET`, set at compile time.

---

### Per-console loglevels

As an aside, after my [patches to make console loglevel per-console](https://lkml.org/lkml/2022/5/20/572) get merged into the kernel, one will be able to reduce or increase the loglevel present for a particular class of consoles directly instead of affecting the whole system using controls in sysfs:

```
% ls -l /sys/class/console/ttyS/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 20 14:40 subsystem -> ../../../../class/console/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 14:41 effective_loglevel
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 14:41 effective_loglevel_source
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 14:41 enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 14:41 loglevel
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 14:40 uevent
```

The format is still a little in flux, but it will likely look similar to this when it gets merged in the next few kernel releases. `kernel.printk` will also likely be deprecated in favour of more granular controls.

See `Documentation/admin-guide/per-console-loglevel.rst` in [the patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2022/5/20/572) for more information.

Comment: ```dmesg: unknown level 0```

Comment: ```ls: cannot access /sys/class/console/ttyS/: No such file or directory```

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira As I said, the per-console loglevel controls are in my *proposed* patch which will land in the next few kernel versions, they're not upstream yet. And strangely yes, klogctl() seems to only take down to loglevel 1, whereas elsewhere we're perfectly happy with 0. For now you can use `sudo dmesg -n1` which will reduce the number of messages dramatically.

Comment: ```sysctl -a | grep kernel.printk``` give  me output, ```kernel.printk=7 4 1 7```. This is happened if I reboot, so does it mean I must execute ```sysctl kernel.printk='0 4 0 5'``` everytime after I reboot OS?. No, I think I must put it in ```init.d``` as bootscript?

Comment: Okay thank you so this is fixed my issue by using ```sysctl kernel.printk='0 4 0 5'```, the only need finishing is I must execute it everytime I reboot, because kernel.printk will be default value if I reboot OS . Any Idea how do I make it permanently?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira As mentioned in the answer, you can persist it in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or `/etc/sysctl.d` (with systemd). See `man 5 sysctl.conf`. Your init system then needs to load the sysctls. If you are running a very bare bones distro, you need to hook up to `sysctl -p`.

Comment: I'm using ```sysvinit``` not ```systemd```